# The column space of a block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times l$ and $n\times k$ matrices, respectively, such that $\operatorname{rank}([A \quad B])=l+k$ and let $v$ with $\|v\|=1$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^k\setminus\{0\}$. Is there a vector $w\ne \pm v$ with $\|w\|=1$ such that
$$
Bw\in \operatorname{Col}([A\quad Bv])?
$$

---

If $Bw\in \operatorname{Col}([A\quad Bv])$, then there exists a vector $x$ such that
$$
Bw=[A\quad Bv]x
$$
or
$$
B^{\top}Bw=B^{\top}[A\quad Bv]x,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
w=(B^{\top}B)^{-1}B^{\top}[A\quad Bv]x.
$$
So, the question is whether there a vector $x$ other than $[0,0,\ldots,\pm 1]^{\top}$ such that the norm of the RHS is 1.

Comment: Please add a bit of context. What about $w=-v$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for catching that. What I had in mind is that $w$ is not a multiple of $v$. BTW, I am trying to formulate the underlying problem and this question arose as a small sub-problem.

Comment: It seems to me that the condition on the rank of $(A\ B)$ says that whenever we have a vector of the form $Ax+By$, then the component vectors $Ax$ and $By$ are uniquely determined. Meaning that $Bw$ can be an element of the column space of $(A\ Bv)$ only when $Bw$ is a scalar multiple of $Bv$. Because the null space of $B$ is trivial, this means that $w$ must be a multiple of $v$. What am I missing?

Comment: In other words, if $$Bw=Ax+\lambda Bv,\quad(*)$$ then we must have $Ax=0$, for otherwise the rank of $(A\ B)$ is strictly less than $k+\ell$. For $(*)$ implies
$$0=Ax+B(\lambda v-w)$$
which is a  linear dependency relation among the columns of $A$ and $B$ unless $x=0$ as well as $w=\lambda v$. Observe thaat both $A$ and $B$ where assumed to have full rank.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's a great observation. Intuitively, I was thinking in the same direction.